# ajax script and tls

Tags: ssl, ajax

I'm using AJAX to get a resource from a server that uses SSL/TLS protocols.  I have to make sure that the AJAX call uses TLS.  How can I do that?  Is setting `https://` in the URL enough?

Here is an exampe:

```
var urlServizi = 'https://........'
var soapMessage =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                          xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
    <soap:Body>\
    <Login xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">\
    <UserName>AAA</UserName>\
    <Password>BBB</Password>\
    <lingua>en</lingua>\
    </Login>\
    </soap:Body>\
    </soap:Envelope>';

    $.ajax({
           url: urlServizi,
           type: "POST",
           async: true,
           dataType: "text",
           data: soapMessage,
           contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
           success: functionOK,
           error: functionKO
           });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how to make the request over HTTPS instead of HTTP then yes, you're right.

If you're asking how to force TLS instead of something like SSL3 (in order to avoid the POODLE vulnerability for example) then you can't in Javascript code.  The browser / user-agent has to be configured to use TLS when establishing secure connections.  Using HTTPS in the URL is the right way to start, but you aren't necessarily guaranteed to use TLS by just doing that.  Only if your user-agent is configured to do so.

Comment: Thanks!!
I have to force TLS, so how can i configure my user-agent to do that?
I have control only on the services structure and the client-side.
Servers are build by third part.

Comment: It depends on what your user agent is. It will be different for each. Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc. It's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Ok i get it. So in my case i have a mobile application that call a service on secure server that use ssl/tls protocols, through ajax. I have to be sure that, when server's developers will enable only tls protocol, my call continue to function with HTTPS; it will be so?

Comment: You will have to research the platforms that your app will be developed for to know for sure.  I only have limited experience with developing for mobile platforms (and only Android at that) so I'm afraid I can't help you much there.  You could post a new question that is specific to the platform you are interested in.